# How to check card decline with stripe api before refresh of user content?

Tags: javascript, ajax, stripe-payments

I follow stripe tutorial:
https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form

It works. But I am slightly worried - what happens if the stripe create token for card that will be still declined?

When I post the data to server to make charge and find out that card cannot be charged, it will be to late to get back to user a restore the content in browser.

My solution is to send the token to my server with AJAX and return status of the charge and redirect user to some "success page" after if the charge was ok. If the AJAX return negative message, I can still ask user for different card in the same form.

In tutorial code I just replaced the line:

```
$form.get(0).submit();
```

with line

```
$.post('/payment/', $form.serialize())
```

I have two questions now:

1. Is it possible to get stripe token for card what will be declined during charge? How common is it? Should I care about this?
2. Is the solution with AJAX call to check the charge status correct? Is it save? It adds one more request and make everything slightly more complicated, so I am not sure if is it worthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to response I get from stripe api helpdesk:

1. Stripe api can create token for card what is not chargeable.
2. It makes sense and it is correct approach to use AJAX to prevent redirect before the charge is successfully made.